# Get radio button value by name in group with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Say i have a radio button group like so:

```
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" value="Hello 1" />Hello 1<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" value="Hello 2" />Hello 2<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" value="Hello 3" />Hello 3<br/>
```

Can i access one of these elements based on the index in the group?

For example I would like to target the second element?

How can this be done in javascript?

Comment: I guess not but if you're allowed to use jquery, look at `$.index()` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

It returns an array of HTML elements. Then you can loop through the returned array by indexing and get the element you want.

So in your question (target the second element) you should use:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('mygroup');
    radios[1].value;
```

And in a more generic way you should use:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('mygroup');

for(i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
console.log(radios[i].value);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WsSSQ/)

Comment: As clarification: `radios[1]` refers to the second element in the `radios` array, that contains all elements with `"mygroup"` as name. (Arrays indexes start at `0`)